# How to add columnDefinitions into md-table from my component content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm starting in Angular 2 and didn't found anything like this.

How I said in the title, I've a component with column definitions set in content, like this:

```
        <tabela-com-consulta [dataSource]="ds">
            <ng-container cdkColumnDef="id">
                <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header >ID</md-header-cell>
                <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</md-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container cdkColumnDef="nome">
                <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header>Name</md-header-cell>
                <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</md-cell>
            </ng-container>
        </tabela-com-consulta>
```

Now this is my component template:

```
<div id="ls" fxFlexFill>
    <md-table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort>
        <!-- Add this for each ContentChildren of my component
                <ng-container cdkColumnDef="id">
                    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header>ID</md-header-cell>
                    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</md-cell>
                </ng-container>
         -->
        <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
        <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
    </md-table>
</div>
```

And the component ts code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tabela-com-consulta',
    templateUrl: 'tabela_com_consulta.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['tabela_com_consulta.component.css']
})
export class TabelaComConsultaComponent<T> implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

[...]

    @ContentChildren(CdkColumnDef) columnDefinitions: QueryList<CdkColumnDef>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to use the columnDefinitions taken from @ContentChildren to put in md-table content. And I don't know if I'm doing this right too. My goal is have the column definitions in content of my component and get it into the md-table. How to do that?

Comment: `<ng-container cdkColumnDef="**nome**">` Are you sure this isn't a typo?

Comment: For everyone that need something like this, I've found another way [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't know if it will work, but worth a shot.

```
<md-table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort>

  <!-- This will selectively pass the content of 'tabela-com-consulta' -->
  <ng-content select="[cdkColumnDef]"></ng-content>

  <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
  <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
</md-table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, still getting error from md-table: ERROR Error: cdk-table: Could not find column with id "id".
    at getTableUnknownColumnError (http://localhost:52686/dist/vendor.js?v=229_tiizAgVyplzgNHmvuD9nw-v9A0XTy8pogI_TkFc:40683:12) .. ..